# SwiftUI - Sign in with Apple crash on watchOS

Tags: watchkit, swiftui, watchos, apple-sign-in

I am implementing **Sign in with Apple** on watchOS using SwiftUI.

Since the `WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton` doesn't conform to the View protocol I am wrapping it using `WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable` to use it in a SwiftUI view.

I have implemented a Coordinator to handle taps on the button and it also acts as a delegate for the Sign up process callbacks.

Below is my code:

```
struct AppleLoginButton: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {

    typealias WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable = WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<AppleLoginButton>

    func updateWKInterfaceObject(_ wkInterfaceObject: WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<AppleLoginButton>) {
        // No code required
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

        @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton) {

            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
            authorizationController.delegate = self
            authorizationController.performRequests()
        }

        func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
            if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
                // Verify the user
            }
        }

        func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
            // Handle error.
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    func makeWKInterfaceObject(context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<AppleLoginButton>) -> WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
        return WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.buttonPressed(_:)))
    }

}
```

Whenever I tap the Sign in button the App crashes with the following error every time,

> **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x74747572)**

can anybody help me if something is wrong with my code or the way I have implemented the Coordinator ?

However the above code works on iOS in SwiftUI with `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` button

And further if I implement Sign in with Apple in WatchKit it works without any issues.

So it seems that I am missing some implementation detail, would love some help on this.

**Update:**
I googled for *EXC* errors and most answers point to illegal memory access as the culprit for these crashes.

Further googling for target-action crashes revealed that if the target is released from the memory pool it leads to crashes.

So can anyone help how can I keep the Coordinator in memory without it getting autoreleased ?

Comment: What’s the “weird error”?

Comment: please check have updated the question

Answer (score 7):

I filed a Feedback with Apple regarding this issue, and they replied with the following fix.

WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton does not trigger the action with a sender parameter. The fix here is to stop specifying a sender parameter on buttonPressed. So:

```
@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton)
```

becomes

```
@objc func buttonPressed()
```

Then line:

```
WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.buttonPressed(_:)))
```

becomes

```
WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.buttonPressed))
```

The above changes fixes my issue and I have tested the same on a real device.
Hope someone finds this useful.